# How to tag Xbox account related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Do we have a tag for Xbox account-related question?
Today [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/403241/87579) was asked, and OP wants to send Xbox friend requests after connecting their Xbox account to another service.

The question was tagged with [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) and [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one), but it doesn't feel right to me, because it's not related to a specific console, but to their Xbox account, and we don't have any tag for that. As far as I know.

When a question like this is asked for Playstation we use [psn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psn), on Switch we have [nintendo-account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-account).

So I created [xbox-account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-account), but I'm not sure if this is the correct choice.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about `[xbox-live]`? IIRC that covers all online services and is cross-generation

Comment: @Robotnik it could work, but a merge/rename it's probably needed since now the service is called [Xbox Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_network).

Comment: I think we've generally always just used the xbox live tag, which as you said probably should be merged now (ive done so). It *may* be worth having some sort of specific xbox account tag, but we've gotten this far without it so I don't know...

Comment: @TimmyJim since we use `[psn]` for Playstation, `[xbox-live]` can work for Xbox. Thanks for the merge, also because you're on strike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, simply use the [xbox-network](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-network) tag for these questions about Xbox accounts.